# Show span on input focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two text fields that bind with `<span>` to count total length of a characters.

I have applied `ng-if` condition.

But my scenario is that it should only show characters left text when the respective `textarea` is `focused`.

[image]

```
<textarea ng-model="goal.goal_name"
 required ng-focus="openFullcreateGoalController()" maxlength="90" placeholder="Write your title here"></textarea>
 <span ng-if="goal.goal_name && !goal.goal_description">{{90 - goal.goal_name.length}}characters left</span>

  <textarea msd-elastic ng-model="goal.goal_description" required placeholder="Add description" maxlength="140"></textarea>
   <span ng-if="goal.goal_description">{{90 - goal.goal_description.length}}characters left</span>
```

My code only shows it if another one is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the css [:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) rule

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.goal = {
    goal_name: 'goal_name',
    goal_description: 'goal_description'
  };
})
```

```css
textarea.charleft + span {
  display: none;
}
textarea.charleft:focus + span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <textarea ng-model="goal.goal_name" class="charleft" required maxlength="90" placeholder="Write your title here"></textarea>
    <span ng-if="goal.goal_name">{{90 - goal.goal_name.length}}characters left</span>

    <textarea msd-elastic class="charleft" ng-model="goal.goal_description" required placeholder="Add description" maxlength="140"></textarea>
    <span ng-if="goal.goal_description">{{90 - goal.goal_description.length}}characters left</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one more thing how can i change color of **span** on reaching maximum limit